# Python/ Django - log name of calling function

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a django app with two management commands, which both call a common library. Lets call them sync_a and sync_b. I want the log entry to record the calling function (or module), so that I know if the log message comes from sync_a or sync_b

```
# sync_a.py
from utils.some_module import some_function
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    some_function('a')

# sync_b.py
from utils.some_module import some_function
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    some_function('a')

# some_module.py
def some_function(param):
    logger.info("running")
```

My logging settings in settings.py are:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'semi_verbose': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(module)s %(name)s %(funcName)s(): %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'semi_verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'app': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'debug',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

The log messages I'm seeing are of the format:

```
[INFO] utils.some_module some_function(): running
```

I'd like them to include either sync_a or sync_b.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is unusual or if I've configured things incorrectly. I know that I could customise the log.info() line to use the parameter or to use inspect, but I'm trying to find a solution that works without needing to do this because I have several management commands and libraries that I'd like it to work across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the Python logging [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html), and it doesn't look like the [`LogRecord`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects) captures the information you're looking for.

If I were going to do this, I think I would write a custom [`Formatter`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) that could look up and add call stack information to the logging call.  The [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module's [stack](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect-stack) function is probably the best way to do that.